# How to deviate a leaf to container in Yang?

Tags: yang

Vice versa would work as well. I looked in RFC#6020 but cannot think of how to do this. The container contains 4 leaves. I was planning to do a deviate replace, but am unable to figure out how the container could be added.

Comment: It is unclear what you try to achieve. Add more information how the module currently looks like and how the final module should look like. In case you want to add a new node (leaf, container, etc.) to an existing node you probably want to use [the augment statement](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6020#page-93).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`deviate not-supported`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-7.20.3.2) to remove schema nodes and the [`augment`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-7.17) statement to add schema nodes. However, since the `augment`ing nodes will be namespace-prefixed by the module identifier of the augmenting module, there's no way to change, say, a leaf `/example:foo` into a container `/example:bar`.

What do you need this for?